# Determine if a phone number has sms messages in android

Tags: android, sms

Is there a way to tell if a phone number has an sms(s) in android ??

I want to know if there is a way to tell using the sms content porvider I know its not documented and not recommanded to use but is there a way to tell ??

what i have tried .

this statement will get all the inbox sms(s)

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null,
                            null);
```

I cant use the where clause like this

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), "address =?", new String[]{"001435436654747"}, null,
                            null);
```

because the number may be stored without the global code the "001" or such . 
is there a work around for this ??

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use below code to do this , I use this in my application to listen incoming sms to reply automaticaly.

```
Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[] {
            "_id", "address", "date", "body",
            "read" }, null, null, null);   

    System.out.println(Number);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
       Number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();

        if (Number.equals("001435436654747")) {

            // DO YOUR STUFF

        }

    }
```